# How can I write this function without using $apply() in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little event hander responding to the up/down keys like this...

```
    $scope.$on('handleDownKey', function(){ changeIndex(1) });
    $scope.$on('handleUpKey', function(){ changeIndex(-1) });

    function changeIndex(val){
        $scope.listIndex += val;
        //$scope.$apply();
    }
```

And in my view I have a list that looks a little like this

```
<li ng-class="{selected: listIndex == $index}" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    <p>{{item.desc}}</p>
</li>
```

The issue I have is that changes to `listIndex` are only reflected in the view when I uncomment the `$scope.apply()` line.

But when I uncomment that line, I get an `Error: $digest already in progress` message when the App loads.

My guess is that I'm just not doing this in an Angular way, but how should an example like this be written in Angular?

For those wondering where `handleKeyDown` comes from, I have a directive that takes keyboard events and passes them to a service called KeyboardSrv. The directive looks like this...

```
myModule.directive('onKeydown', function(KeyboardSrv) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        function applyKeydown() {
          scope.$apply(attrs.onKeydown);
        };           

        elm.bind('keydown', function(evt) {
            KeyboardSrv.prepareEvent(evt)
        });
    };
});
```

And the service looks like this...

```
function KeyboardSrv($rootScope){

    var KeyboardSrv = {};       
    KeyboardSrv.code;
    KeyboardSrv.evt;

    KeyboardSrv.prepareEvent = function(evt){
        KeyboardSrv.code = evt.which;
        KeyboardSrv.evt = evt;

        if(KeyboardSrv.code == 40){
            KeyboardSrv.broadcastEvent("handleDownKey", evt);
        }

        if(KeyboardSrv.code == 38){
            KeyboardSrv.broadcastEvent("handleUpKey", evt);
        }

    }

    KeyboardSrv.broadcastEvent = function(msg, event){
        $rootScope.$broadcast(msg, event);
    }

    return KeyboardSrv;

};
```

Comment: why not doing it with a directives?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but there are other things going on in the controller related to the listIndex, so it seems like the right place for it to be.

Comment: Are you trying to communicate between two controllers?

Comment: Who fires `handleUpKey`?

Comment: I've created a directive that handles keyboard events. All events are intercepted by a service called KeryboardService which looks at which key was pressed and triggers the event on the $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a way to handle this in Angular without triggering an error. Basically, angular will pick up this change whenever it runs `$digest`. The problem I have here is that my `changeIndex` method isn't triggering `$digest`, so I have to call `$apply` manually.

However, when the app starts, the `changeIndex` method is called, whilst `$digest` is still running, which triggers an error because you can't have a call to `$digest` inside another call to `$digest`.

Angular does provide a way to tell wether `$digest` is currently running so the call to `$apply` should be handled like this...

```
$scope.listIndex += val
if(!$$phase) $scope.$apply();
```

if `$$phase` is true, then angular is currently running `$digest` and our changes will be picked up automagically. if `$$phase` is false, then we need to trigger `$apply` manually.

Whilst it's a fix, I would still prefer to not have to call $apply manually. It feels a little bit too much like manual reference counting and having methods that work this way smell funny to me.